# multiple entity type in entity field query

Tags: entities, database

how to add mutilple entity_type and bundles in EntityFieldQuery?

`$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'profile2')
       ->entityCondition('bundle', 'user_profile');`

Is there any way to do like this

`$query->entityCondition('entity_type', array('profile2','user'))
       ->entityCondition('bundle', array('user_profile','property'));`

Comment: can you pls tell me how to add multiple entity_type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', array('profile2','user'))
      ->entityCondition('bundle', array('user_profile','property'), 'IN');
```

Comment: thank you. is there any way to add multiple fieldConditions...? Refer to this Question (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128844/how-to-add-two-fieldconditons-in-entity-field-query)