# How to add two fieldConditons in Entity field Query?

Tags: database

Is this the correct way to add field Conditions

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'profile2')
   ->entityCondition('bundle', 'user_profile')
   ->fieldCondition('field_town_city', 'value', "%".$search_title."%", 'LIKE')
   ->fieldCondition('field_land_state', 'value', "%".$search_title."%", 'LIKE');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can chain multiple field conditions, however I'd probably try something like this (haven't tested it):

```
->fieldCondition('field_town_city', 'value', $search_title, 'CONTAINS')
```

The EntityFieldQuery::fieldCondition() invokes the addFieldCondition() method, see the possible $op values on api.drupal.org:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AaddFieldCondition/7

Comment: can you give a example code?

Comment: @Mukil What do you need example code for exactly? Your code is correct

Comment: when i execute this code `$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'profile2')
       ->entityCondition('bundle', array('user_profile'), IN)
      ->fieldCondition('field_fl_name', 'value', $search_title, 'CONTAINS')
      ->fieldCondition('field_town_city', 'value', $search_title, 'CONTAINS');` it returns empty array.

Comment: how to add OR condition between fieldCondition...?

Comment: @Mukil As far as I know there's no `CONTAINS` in MySQL. OP might be thinking of T-SQL. Just use `LIKE` if your db engine doesn't support it. ORs are tricky with EFQ, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14499/using-or-with-entityfieldquery